# Is it possible to connect a SQL file in VS Code to a .mdb database in MS Access?

Tags: microsoft-access, visual-studio-code, sql

Is it possible to connect the .mdb database file open in Microsoft Access with a .sql file that you edit in Visual Studio Code?

I want to be able to create seperate queries in a .sql file that I edit in VS Code and have the results of the queries be displayed in either VS Code in the output or console, or simply have it displayed in the open file in Microsoft Access.